# How to develop video trimming in android?

Tags: android, video, video-editing

I am used developing the app videos uploading for 10sec thats way i cut the  video for 10sec.I do lot of research but getting any proper result.please tell me anyone .This is most important for me.If u want to give the solution most favourable for me. Is there any default video editing feature in android.
Advance thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Recently i had same problem and did some research about that. I found 2 solutions

First one is easier but have limitations. If you're using mp4 files you can try [mp4Parser](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/97119/Mobile-App-Development-Working-With-Media-Files-on-Android-Part-2/).
I manage to trim videos pretty easy from the trimming videos example.

Second one is very flexible but much harder to use. If are in need give it a try and use [FFmpeg library](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). I believe it is written in c or c++ so you need to use NDK to compile it and force it to run on Android. There are plenty of tutorials ([for example from roman10](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)) how to do so. Notice that people sugest to do it on linux because its much more easier than on Windows. (I didn't manage to compile it on Windows).

Comment: when i trim the portrait video its changes to orientation(Landscape)and also changes the video orientation by mp4Parser

Comment: MP4Parser has Apache 2.0 license. Github project: https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

Comment: Check this updated answer in Kotlin

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501049/how-to-trim-the-video-with-start-end-time-in-android-programmatically/65741422#65741422