# How to trim the video with start & end time in android programmatically?

Tags: android, video, android-library, video-editing

I want to trim the local video based on start and end time in android programmatically ,I tried below attached few links but haven't worked for me.Please let me know any working libraries or sample code to overcome this?

Refereed links:

1. [Android sdk cut/trim video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205299/android-sdk-cut-trim-video-file)
2. [How to trim the video using FFMPEG library in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901935/how-to-trim-the-video-using-ffmpeg-library-in-android)
3. https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Use FFMPEG library to solve your problem. Thanks for writingminds to make ffmpeg simple for android 
 1. `implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'`

2. initialize ffmpeg

   ```
   private void setUpFFmpeg() {
   ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);


   try {
       ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

           @Override
           public void onStart() {
               Log.d("Event ", "onStart");
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure() {
               Log.d("Event ", "onFailure");
           }

           @Override
           public void onSuccess() {
               Log.d("Event ", "onSuccess");
           }

           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
               Log.d("Event ", "onFinish");

           }
       });
   } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
       // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
   }
   }
   ```
3. use [FFMPEG command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50501220/9558451) like @Mahesh Keshvala posted above. Good work @Mahesh
4. then `execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);` will be like this

   ```
   private void execFFmpegBinary(String[] command){
         try {

       ffmpeg.execute(commands, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

           @Override
           public void onStart() {
               Log.d("Event ", "onStart");
           }

           @Override
           public void onProgress(String message) {
               Log.e("Event ", "onProgress - " + message);

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(String message) {
               Log.e("Event ", "onFailure - " + message);

           }

           @Override
           public void onSuccess(String message) {
               Log.e("Event ", "onSuccess - " + message);

           }

           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
               Log.e("Event ", "onFinish");

           }
       });
   } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
       // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
   }
   ```

try command for cut video

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-s", "320x240", "-r", "15", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

to know more about ffmpeg android refer [this link](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/)

Comment: Showing below error while executing execFFmpegBinary block.

Error:

E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@dbe0367
    java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/com.psp.testvideotrim/files/ffmpeg, -ss, 0, -y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/test/Media/test Video/VID-20180522-WA0008.mp4, -t, 3, -vcodec, mpeg4, -b:v, 2097152, -b:a, 48000, -ac, 2, -ar, 22050, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/cut_video.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: 05-24 11:10:52.474 19740-19740/com.psp.testvideotrim E/Event: onFailure - 
05-24 11:10:52.475 19740-19740/com.psp.testvideotrim E/Event: onFinish

Comment: i update my answer please check that, also refer that [link](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/) too. I use the same method in one of my project

Comment: this is not working on android 10.you can use this library https://github.com/a914-gowtham/Android-video-trimmer

Comment: @gowtham6672 Link is broken i think library is not maintained anymore.

Comment: check that link now @RahulChaudhary

Comment: This answer will not work for SDK level greater than 9. You can check my updated answer below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501049/how-to-trim-the-video-with-start-end-time-in-android-programmatically/65741422#65741422

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using FFMPEG library use below function to trim or cut the video, may this will work for you:

```
private void executeCutVideoCommand(int startMs, int endMs) {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
    );

    String filePrefix = "cut_video";
    String fileExtn = ".mp4";
    String yourRealPath = getPath(VideoEffectActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);
    File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
    int fileNo = 0;
    while (dest.exists()) {
        fileNo++;
        dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: startMs: " + startMs);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: endMs: " + endMs);
    filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    //String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};
    String[] complexCommand = {"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath};

    execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);

}


 private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
               //You have to create a class of Preview Activity
               //If you don't have please remove below Intent code
                    Intent intent = new Intent(VideoEffectActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                    progressDialog.setMessage("progress : " + s);
                Log.d(TAG, "progress : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);
               progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
```

Put this dependency into gradle file:

```
    compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

Comment: "execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);" Showing error even integrating the above library?

Comment: Unable to create "execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);"

Below " Sam Raju " answer helped me to create that.

Comment: Showing below error while executing execFFmpegBinary block.

Error:

   E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@a1d6f03
    java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/com.psp.testvideotrim/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp Business/Media/WhatsApp Business Video/VID-20180522-WA0000.mp4, -ss, 0, -t, 30, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/cut_video.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: please check all the conditions you put like permission read,write and access of storage and all that may be because of that you get this error.

Comment: I have given all permissions too...But Error still persists@mahes Keshavala

Comment: use this library https://github.com/a914-gowtham/Android-video-trimmer

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution **ffmpeg library** in Kotlin. This solution is tested with SDK Versions 21 to 30.

First, you need to add the dependency

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.2.LTS'
```

Below, is the code snippet for trimming the video.

Note: You need to run the below code inside the background thread by using AsyncTask or Kotlin Coroutines

```
val outputFile = UtilsFile.createVideoFile(context)
        val command =
            arrayOf(
                "-ss",
                "1",    //Start point in seconds
                "-y",
                "-i",
                inputFile.absolutePath,
                "-t",
                "60",   //Ending point in seconds
                "-s",
                "648x1152",
                "-r",
                "15",
                "-vcodec",
                "mpeg4",
                "-b:v",
                "2097152",
                "-b:a",
                "48000",
                "-ac",
                "2",
                "-ar",
                "22050",
                outputFile.absolutePath
            )
        val rc = FFmpeg.execute(command)

        if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Command execution completed successfully.")
            return outputFile
        } else if (rc == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Command execution cancelled by user.")
        } else {
            Log.i(
                TAG,
                String.format(
                    "Command execution failed with rc=%d and the output below.",
                    rc
                )
            )
        }
```